# Python Pandas: Sort an alphanumeric dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe as following.

| No | ID | Sub_No | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a23mcsk | 2 | 30 |
| 2 | smcd302 | 3 | 60 |
| 3 | a23mcsk | 1 | 24 |
| 4 | smcd302 | 2 | 45 |
| 5 | a23mcsk | 3 | 18 |
| 6 | smcd302 | 1 | 12 |

I want to be able to sort this dataframe first by 'ID' and then by the 'Sub_No'. Is there a way I can do this on Python using Pandas?

Expected Result:

| No | ID | Sub_No | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | a23mcsk | 1 | 24 |
| 1 | a23mcsk | 2 | 30 |
| 5 | a23mcsk | 3 | 18 |
| 6 | smcd302 | 1 | 12 |
| 4 | smcd302 | 2 | 45 |
| 2 | smcd302 | 3 | 60 |

Comment: Do you need sort by number from `ID` ? Or sorting by 2 columns?

Comment: Oh, so you want to sort by the number in the ID ?  That is, "b21mcsk" should come before 'a23mcsk' in the outcome ?   This is not what your original question is mentioning.  Suggest to edit your question if so.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use helper column here for correct sorting by numeric values from `ID` with `Sub_No`:

```
df['new'] = df['ID'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)

df = df.sort_values(by=['new', 'Sub_No'], ascending=False).drop('new', axis=1)
```

Another idea with natural sorting:

```
import natsort as ns

df['new'] = pd.Categorical(df['ID'], ordered=True, categories= ns.natsorted(df['a'].unique()))
df = df.sort_values(by=['new', 'Sub_No'], ascending=False).drop('new', axis=1)
```

Comment: How is this method differing from the other methods suggested below?

Comment: @AkhilKintali - This extract `number` from `ID` and it is used for sorting.

Comment: @AkhilKintali - Another answer sorting by `ID`

Comment: This actually is an answer that does not what is asked for. Given the following case:

    df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a5222mcsk', 'smcd302', 'a5222mcsk','smcd302'],'Sub_No': [2,3,1,2]})

it would not sort by ID but only by the number which is not intended nor stated. Sadly, the answer is though accepted.

Comment: @KaRaOkEy - Added solution for natural sorting by `ID`

Comment: While I still do not see the necessity for such a complex sorting, it at least produces a reliable result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Sub_No'], ascending=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Sub_No'])
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Fully agree with what you said in general.  That's also my practice to give explanations in almost all my answers.  However, bear in mind that there are cases that the answer is simple enough and self-explanatory.  This is the case especially when coding syntax is what's required and enough.  Thanks for your suggestion anyway where it gives all of us a general guideline.